# SATELLITE M40X-129 GR, display is not turning on. How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, display

Greetings, I have a SATELLITE M40X-129 GR. The laptop was working. I decided that I want to remove the OEM windows and go for a linux distro. I got the dvd of a linux distro, restarted the laptop, pressed the f12 key to boot from dvd and display suddenly went off. From that point I wasn't able to turn it on no more. Tried a lot of restarts, removed the battery and power plug then pressed the power button for like 20 sec, then put the battery back. Nothing seems to work.Tried an external monitor as well, no signal. I tried also to put it in a bright light, but can't see nothing. So it's not the LCD.

What do I do in this instance? I'm not a beginner, and from my point of view I think I have nothing else to do than open the laptop. But how do I troubleshoot in order to find out which component is failing? I suspect maybe it's the video card...but how do I test that? It should actually be burned or what?

Thanks and please let me know if you need other info.

Comment: No one knows???